# Can selenium find location of link and just not search for a specific link?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm building a program that looks over google news and gets the links for the top ten stories, but I'm running into problems. I just can tell it to find a specific link because they change every day. Can selenium find the location where these links would be? if not what can I do?

Comment: use XPath for defined a static location.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding an element which contains the uniquely identify the URLs. I saw the HTML and noticed that the links are all within a `<h2>` tag with class `'esc-lead-article-title'`. So by simply using xpath I was able to fetch the URLs.

```
links = driver.get_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='esc-lead-article-title']/a")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("url"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the url's using "href" tagName.

Try to use below selenium Java sample code :

```
    List<WebElement> links = mDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (WebElement link : links) {
        System.out.println("LInk= " + link.getAttribute("href"));
    }
```